# Which spring grpc boot starter project should I use?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, grpc, grpc-java

We are at the beginning of developing with microservices using gRPC. Our microservices are designed to be run on JVM. Inside our persistence layer, we would like to use an ORM library. Spring Data JPA project looks very promising.

But there are a two spring-grpc-boot-starter projects out there?

- https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter
- https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter

Which one should I use? Or do you recommend any other one or method?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, [saturnism](https://github.com/saturnism/grpc-spring-boot-starter) and [Salesforce](https://github.com/salesforce/grpc-java-contrib/tree/master/contrib/grpc-spring) also have grpc+spring boot starter projects.

I know nothing about Spring Boot myself, but I've been told LogNet's is pretty nice and it also discusses service discovery. But Salesforce's should be considered as well.

Comment: Thank you. We have started depending on LogNet's implementation.